# Jetty: HTTP ERROR: 503/ Service Unavailable after change the server ip address WHEN NO INTERNET CONNECTION

Tags: http-status-code-503, opennms

I did install Opennms in a VM Ubuntu on PROXMOX. Everything went well until I did change the interface IP address because the VM must work in a LAN without Internet access. Since then the opennms start correctly but the browser give me the error:

Jetty: HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /opennms/. Reason:

Service Unavailable

The problem seems to be related with the connection to Internet at the starting of opennms. When I start opens without Internet connection the server do to start correctly.

Comment: Hello, Adding some information, I did observe that the problem is not for the IP address but for the internet connection. The 503 error only appear if the opennms server has been started without internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenNMS has a bugfix that may take care of it.

http://issues.opennms.org/browse/NMS-7683